# Replacing a character in $args

Tags: nginx

I want to replace each `+` with  (space) in `$args`.

I know the solution of

```
if ($args ~ ^(.*)\+(.*)$) {
  return 301 "$uri?$1 $2";
}
```

However that's not ideal because there's a redirect for each `+`. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use more than one regular expression. Each regular expression tests the `$args` parameter for one, two, three, etc. `+` characters (evaluated in reverse order) which will minimise the recursion.

A compact solution uses a `map` to define the regular expressions.

For example:

```
map $args $spaces {
    default 0;
    ~^(.*)\+(.*)\+(.*)\+(.*)\+(.*)$  "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5";
    ~^(.*)\+(.*)\+(.*)\+(.*)$        "$1 $2 $3 $4";
    ~^(.*)\+(.*)\+(.*)$              "$1 $2 $3";
    ~^(.*)\+(.*)$                    "$1 $2";
}
server {
    ...
    if ($spaces) { return 301 "$uri?$spaces"; }
    ...
}
```

You can use more or less regular expressions to optimise the solution. The above will generate one redirection for up to four `+` characters, and two redirections for between five and eight `+` characters, and so on.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

Comment: Not a pretty solution since it requires hardcoding and is less maintainable with a large number of replacements, but it works.

Comment: What if the number of +s are unknown and could be an arbitrary number? Is there no way to handle that?

Comment: @user2399453 The above solution should also work if there are more than 5 spaces. After the first 5 `+`s are converted, the browser will make a request with the converted URL, which will cause another 5 `+`s to be converted. This will repeat until the browser gives up.